# How to redirect to the current page with form in php?

Tags: php, forms

I tried to redirect to the current page with form in my php application. Now i have met a problem.

```
<form name="myform" action="?page=matching" method="GET">

<input id="match_button" type="submit" name="button" value="button" onClick="func_load3()" />

</form>
```

`action="?page=matching"` means the current page, because i use the single entry in my php application.

With the code upon, When i click the button, it redirects to the homepage.

And I tried to use:

```
<form name="myform" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="GET">
```

but it still doesn't work.

So i have to ask for help from you. Do you have any ideas about that? How to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What *does* happen if you use $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']? Error? Homepage?

Comment: Yes, it redirects to homepage. I don't know how to solve it. Could you help me ?

Answer (score 14):

leave the action part empty to redirect to current page eg:

```
<form action="">
```

or if you want to redirect to some other page, you can do so like this:

```
<form action="somepage.php">  // page must be in the same directory
```

If you want to append query string then:

```
<form action="somepage.php?var=value&var2=value">
```

If you want to redirect to a page one directory back then:

```
<form action="../somepage.php?var=value&var2=value">
```

Two directories:

```
<form action="../../somepage.php?var=value&var2=value"> and so on
```

inside a nother folder

```
<form action="yourfolder/somepage.php?var=value&var2=value">
```

Comment: @Thanks Sarfraz Ahmed, I've used the two ways you recommended. It doesn't work because when i use "somepage.php", i can find the page. I have used the single index page to control the access to all the other pages.

Comment: then you can specify that like this too action="index.php?page=yourpage"

Comment: I have changed it. I have no idea why it doesn't work. Frustrated.

Answer (score 2):

PHP_SELF doesnt include Query string, you have to tag that on the end

```
<?php
$formAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) { 
    $formAction .= "?" . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; 
}
?>
```

then set that as your form action:

```
<form name="myform" action="<?=$formaction;?>" method="GET">
```

Thou i guess just doing:

```
<form name="myform" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']. "?" . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];?>" method="GET">
```

Might work too, not sure what it will do if the QUERY_STRING is empty thou

Comment: @thanks, i've tried this way. <form name="myform" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page=matching'; ?>" method="GET">. Why is it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
<form name="myform" method="GET">
  <input type="hidden" name="page" value="matching" />
  <input id="match_button" type="submit" name="button" value="button" onClick="func_load3()" />
</form>
```

Alsoy, the JS function func_load needs not to redirect the page to somewhere.

Comment: @BenoKrapo, Thanks, i think the hidden input is not working in this case.

Answer (score 0):

`$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]` is probably index.php. Have you looked at it? You need:

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']. '?page=matching'; ?>
```

I recommend to build a link helper that manages your routes.

Comment: @Thanks ereno, with the code: <form name="myform" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page=matching'; ?>" method="GET">. It redirects to the index.php. I think you're right, but i don't know why it's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

try this
index.php:

```
switch ($_REQUEST['site']){
  case 'somethings':      
     if ($_POST['k_send']){ 
       //somethings
     }
  ...
```

form.php

```
<form name="send" action="index.php?site=somethings" 
  <input ...
  <input type="submit" name="k_send" ...
```

Comment: @turbod, it's exactly what i have done, but the "action" part is always not working. After i submit, the URL is "index.php?select1=1&select2=1&select3=1&ref=interet&button=button". There is no "matching" page.

Comment: this work only post method, dont work the get method.
<code>
<?php
switch ($_REQUEST['site']){
    case 'addcart':
        print $_POST['first'];
        break;
    default:
    break;
}
?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>?site=addcart" name="myform" method="post" >
 <input name="first" type="text" />
 <input type="submit" value="ok" name="akcio" />
</form>
</code>

Answer (score 0):

Work only with post method.